# What's the longest crewed space mission flight ever?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, record

I wonder what the longest single space mission ever was/is. This question doesn't ask for the longest single spaceflight of a human (this are Valery Polyakov's 437 d 18 h on Mir who launched with Soyuz TM-18 and landed with Soyuz TM-20) but for the longest space mission or one could say for the longest flight of a (crewed) spacecraft. This is something that [isn't mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spaceflight_records#Duration_records). This isn't about space stations either unless the crew (or most of it) on the space station returned *in the same spacecraft* they launched from Earth with (and the spacecraft remained docked as long as the crew was on the station).

The longest U.S. space mission was Skylab 4 (~ 84 d) and the longest Chinese one was Shenzhou 11 (~ 32.5 d). While these missions look record-suspicious, the longest single mission must have been a Russian one because the Russian Soyuz spacecraft remain docked to Mir and to the ISS very long. As per [this list](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_bemannten_Raumfl%C3%BCge)
the longest single Russian space mission seems to have been Soyuz TMA-9 at ~ 215 days. Is this the longest space mission ever?

Comment: It's hard to see how you can't answer this yourself as you've already done the research. Your definition of mission duration is a bit odd, missions are over when the space agency that launched it says they are over.

Comment: @GdD I changed to "space mission flight". What I mean is what is provided in the 2nd link, a list of spaceflights, I don't mean a stay in space of an individual but rather the longest spaceflight in the same spacecraft (which can include the stay on a space station). Also, if I'm right with Soyuz TMA-9, I wonder why it didn't get any public attention afaik, since it's the longest spaceflight ever.